# Generator that takes n iterables and produces n-tuples of the first value in each iterable

Tags: python

```
def myzip(*iterables):
    l = []
    t = tuple()
    x = [iter(a) for a in iterables]
    while True:
        for a in x:
            for i in range(3):
                t = t + tuple(a) 
            l.append(t) 
    for x in l:
        yield x
```

I need to write myzip generator takes any number of iterables (call the number n) it produces n-tuples of the first value in each iterable, the second value of each iterable, etc; if one iterable is exhausted before all the others, its position in the n-tuple should store None.

for instance:

```
for i in myzip('abcde','fg','hijk'):
    print(i,end='')
```

prints the 5 3-tuples `('a','f','h')('b','g','i')('c',None,'j')('d',None,'k')('e',None, None)`.

for some reasons, my program just failed and it did not yield anything.

Comment: Your `yield` statement is outside of the `while True` loop, so it never yields.

Comment: I append everything in the list and yield from the list

Comment: No, look carefully at your indentation. The loop `for x in l` never happens because it's outside the `while True` loop.

Comment: Do you have two accounts? Question formatting is very similar... http://stackoverflow.com/users/7062915/zhangdi

Answer (score 0):

There were several logical issues with your approach.  I created a function that does what you are looking for with a couple improvements.  In particular, the `yield` is called during each iteration of the `while` loop instead of the tuples being stored in a list and sequentially `yield`ed at the end.  Here is my list of things that seemed off:

1. The `while` loop was not terminating (no break)
2. There was a magic number 3 throw in there (seemed to be a hardcoded number of iterables)
3. Rather than use `for ... in ...` syntax to read each iterable, the `next()` function is now used to read the next item in each iterable.
4. When all iterables are exhaused, the `while` loop is now broken

Here is the modified function:

```
def myzip(*iterables):
  x = [iter(a) for a in iterables]
  sentinel = object()
  while True:
    l = []
    valid = False
    for y in x:
      item = next(y, sentinel)
      if item is sentinel:
        item = None
      else:
        valid = True
      l.append(item)
    if not valid:
      break
    yield tuple(l)
```

And a link to it in action:

https://repl.it/FdCD/1